# Problem in prediction of my image in my own trained Keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, keras, computer-vision

I trained my model using transfer learning. Now when I am predicting my image in Colab it shows me an error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 3) for input Tensor("xception_input:0", shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 275, 3).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 3) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 275, 3).

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-142a5ca8cbef> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 classes = np.argmax(model.predict(img), axis=-1)
      3 print(classes)
.
.
.


    ValueError: Input 0 of layer block1_conv1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 275, 3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically during training, you were feeding a batch of images as input the network, the same will be required at the test/evaluation time. So, the easy solution would be to expand the dimension of img tensor to `[1, img.shape]`.

```py
img_test = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying that you trained your model using a shape of

```
shape=(None, 128, 128, 3)
```

but when you try to predict from the model you provided an input of

```
[None, 275, 3]
```

Obviously, this cannot be used by your model. First of all, you provided a 3dim dimension input but you should have provided a 4dim one. Typically images are `(height, width, 3)` and if you provide them in batches this becomes `(batch_size, height, width, 3)` and if you have just one image it becomes:

```
(1, height, width, 3)
```

So, you should check the input you provide your model with. With numpy you typically use something like

```
np.expand_dims(original_image, axis=0)
```

to go from 3dim to 4dim input.

Comment: how can i convert my 3dim input to 4dim?

Comment: As mentioned before you can use numpy or tensorflow approach (basically same syntax) using `expand_dims`